# haproxy raw log file to csv converter

Tags: haproxy

I have some haproxy raw log files, where each lines looks something like this:

```
Feb  6 12:14:14 localhost \
      haproxy[14389]: 10.0.1.2:33317 [06/Feb/2009:12:14:14.655] http-in \
      static/srv1 10/0/30/69/109 200 2750 - - ---- 1/1/1/1/0 0/0 {1wt.eu} \
      {} "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1"
```

**Question**: how can I convert the haproxy raw log files to CSV?

Comment: I've reworded it, but the question is probably better suited for stackoverflow now.

Comment: I can migrate it to SO, if you'd like, though it's perfectly topical here as well, now.  Let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of an existing tool offhand. But you can take the work done with this [logstash grok regex](https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/blob/master/patterns/haproxy), convert to a regex in the language of your choice and spit out the object as csv.

Answer (score 1):

I have been dealing with a similar issue at work recently. I found these pretty helpful:

http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result

https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

I ended up with a generic pattern line like this:

```
pattern => "%{IP:client_ip}:%{INT:client_port} \[%{HAPROXYDATE:accept_date}\] %{NOTSPACE:frontend_name} %{NOTSPACE:backend_name}/%{NOTSPACE:server_name} %{INT:time_request}/%{INT:time_queue}/%{INT:time_backend_connect}/%{INT:time_backend_response}/%{NOTSPACE:time_duration} %{INT:http_status_code} %{NOTSPACE:bytes_read} %{DATA:captured_request_cookie} %{DATA:captured_response_cookie} %{NOTSPACE:termination_state} %{INT:actconn}/%{INT:feconn}/%{INT:beconn}/%{INT:srvconn}/%{NOTSPACE:retries} %{INT:srv_queue}/%{INT:backend_queue} (\{%{HAPROXYCAPTUREDREQUESTHEADERS}\})?( )?(\{%{HAPROXYCAPTUREDRESPONSEHEADERS}\})?( )?\"(<BADREQ>|(%{WORD:http_verb} (%{URIPROTO:http_proto}://)?(?:%{USER:http_user}(?::[^@]*)?@)?(?:%{URIHOST:http_host})?(?:%{URIPATHPARAM:http_request})?( HTTP/%{NUMBER:http_version})?))?\""
```

But it requires `option httplog` adding each of the front ends you are looking to grab metrics for.